# Cost of inserting into a table in an arbitrary position using the INT primary key in SQLite3

Tags: sqlite

I have a question on the mechanism used when we insert some item into table in arbitrary position with an `INT` primary key. I know it will use binary search to execute `SELECT` and `WHERE` with rowid or `INTEGER` primary key. What I want to know is is the query plan use same binary search when it insert with primary key.

The following is the example.

```
CREATE TABLE carBrand
(
    brandID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    branName TEXT
);

INSERT INTO carBrand VALUES (2, 'BMW');
INSERT INTO carBrand VALUES (3, 'KIA');
INSERT INTO carBrand VALUES (5, 'FORD');
INSERT INTO carBrand VALUES (8, 'AUDI');
```

After these commands, what method will the query plan use if I do like

```
INSERT INTO carBrand VALUES (4, 'AUDI');
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#btree is interesting reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primary key columns in SQLite are backed by a B tree index.  So the cost of inserting `(4, 'AUDI')` into your table `carBrand` is the cost of restructuring the primary key index.  In theory, a B tree insert will generally be logarithmic.  In practice, in a database context, a given insert might be slower for a number of reasons.  For example, if a block has no more room, the database might have to search around nearby for other space to write the record, or, in a worse case, maybe even move around entire blocks.

Comment: Thank you. Now it is much clear for me about how it behave with the primary key. I think It would be better to avoid to insert in middle point.

Comment: I might disagree.  Most databases are very optimized, and have tricks to update a clustered or even non clustered index very quickly.  Anyway, if your primary key column is also an auto increment column, then your database would be generating these values automatically.

Comment: In the case of sqlite, it uses a b*-tree for rowid tables, where the actual row data is only in leaf nodes, which helps minimize the shuffling that needs to be done when a node has to be split on an insert. (And all rowid tables are "auto increment"; if you don't specify a rowid, one is picked automatically). (Indexes and WITHOUT ROWID tables use traditional b-trees).

Answer (score 0):

SQLite would just insert it the same way it did the prior inserts. It doesn't do out of order inserts any different than it does in order ones.